# Anchor tag wont render correctly (WordPress PHP)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, anchor

I am trying to add data atributes to my anchor tag for a WordPress custom theme.
The code below is what I've so far, the problem is with plain HTML this works fine but once I add the PHP lines then something breaks.

When the actual HTML is rendered it excludes the end of the open anchor tag, and leaves "> out to display on the page.

Not sure what went wrong but maybe someone can take a look at this and might be able to point out what I did wrong, a fix, a better way, or maybe if this is even possible.

```
<a
class="caption" href="<?php the_permalink()?>"
title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"
data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>"
data-description="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>"
>

<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(301,301)); ?>

</a>


<?php endif; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just some thoughts/things to try:

1. Are those PHP functions defined somewhere on the same page, or on a page that is *included* or *required* ?
2. Have you tried replacing those function calls with simple PHP commands, such as `<?php echo "the_permalink_goes_here"; ?>` etc. -- just to make sure, for example, that the anchor tag's href value changes to

   `<a href="the_permalink_goes_here" etc>`

Comment: I believe the culprit to be the WordPress Jetpack Share plugin. I reactivate all other plugins and kept it off and everything looks great.
`<a
class=​"caption" href=​"site-name" data-title=​"text" data-description=​"
<div class="text">​
</a>​`The share plugin inserts a div tag right before the end of the anchor <div class=" sharedaddy sd-sharing-enabled"> <a/>​​, and throw the img tag out of the anchor. I'm not sure if this is separate from the " > render, but it looks to be related.`<a
class="caption" href="site" data-title="text" data-description="text"
>
<img src="site">
</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The excerpt function that you're using for the description is returning not just the excerpt, but also an additional "Read more" link, effectively putting an anchor inside your anchor tag, which is what is breaking it. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a default WP function for returning an excerpt without this link, so you will need a function to do this. Try searching for 'excerpt without link'